# pylint 'unused_variable' warning on function definition

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I have defined a function in `__init__.py`.
While running pylint on `__init__.py`, it gives a warning about `unused_variable` on the function_name.

I don't want to disable this warning in general (for actual unused variables, etc.) but obviously I don't want a warning for the function definition. Sample `__init__.py`:

```
import os

test_enabled = True
run_all_tests = False     ## Raises 'unused_variable' warning, expected and want to keep such warnings

def is_test_enabled():    ## Raises 'unused_variable' warning, unexpected and want to disable
    return <test_object> if test_enabled else None
```

Comment: i think the warning is because you are not using the run_all_tests variable anywhere in the code you have given

Comment: Hey @PrathameshJadhav. I am getting 2 warnings.  One for run_all_tests, another for is_test_enabled. I have mentioned both (with comments) to highlight my issue.